# Not able to understand output of methods with Optional Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, optional-parameters, overriding

Today I was writing a small program to understand the fundamentals of Optional Parameters of C#.

Following is the program:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    internal abstract void Test();
}

sealed class DerivedClass : AbstractClass
{        
    internal override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In override DerivedClass.Test() method");
    }

    internal void Test(int a = 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In DerivedClass.Test(int a=1) method " + a);
    }

    internal void Test(int b, int a = 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In DerivedClass.Test(int b, int a=1) method " + string.Format("{0} {1}", b, a));
    }
}
```

This is how I called `Test()` method:

```
   DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();       
   d.Test();
   d.Test(6);
   d.Test(b:7);
```

**Output :**

> In DerivedClass.Test(int a=1) method 1
>
> In DerivedClass.Test(int a=1) method 6
>
> In DerivedClass.Test(int b, int a=1) method 7 1

Regarding `d.Test();`: Here my understanding is, it will treat `Test()` as method with an optional parameter, and will invoke `Test(int a = 1)` with this output:

> In DerivedClass.Test(int a=1) method 1

But this is what confuses me when executing `d.Test(6);`: Why this method call isn't giving output as:

> In DerivedClass.Test(int b, int a=1) method 6 1

As per my understanding "6" is the mandatory parameter and it should invoke

```
internal void Test(int b, int a = 1)
```

Kindly explain what is wrong with my understanding.

Also how to call an overriden method?

```
internal override void Test()
```

Comment: Why should `Test(6)` invoke `Test(int b, int a = 1)`? There is already a matching method `Test(int a = 1)`, which is invoked with `a` set to `6`.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Dennis_E But why is `Test(int a = 1)` called in the first case when there is a much better match without any params?

Comment: Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: @HimBromBeere I missed that (you said the confusion was with `d.Test(6)`). It is because the compiler prefers methods that are declared in the class itself, not the base class. So, it chooses the one with the default parameter. The C# method overload resolution can be complex at times and may sometimes do different things than we expect. (I deleted my previous comment btw).

Answer (score 6):

The rule matching for `internal void Test(int a = 1)` matches your code `d.Test(6);` best: it matches on the number of arguments, the types. That makes the method the best match.

When calling `d.Test(b:7);`, you force it to run as the last method, since you are matching on the name of the parameter. That makes the last method the best matching.

The first (`d.Test();`) doesn't match on the method you expected (`void Test()`), since 'own' methods are preferred over derived methods. Try to remove the base class or use the `new` operator on the method and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

The rules around optional parameters can be a little confusing, but a simple rule of thumb to remember is that it'll always use a method with less parameters in preference to one with more.

So for

```
d.Test(6);
```

the method with just one parameter:

```
internal void Test(int a = 1)
```

will be used, even though it's an optional parameter.

Comment: Could you please provide some docs related to this? The MSDN page on Named and Optional Arguments doesn't seem very clear to me.